# How can I add an image to the title bar in android 3.0?

Tags: android

I am learning android 3.0.
Can any one tell How can add Image in Title bar in android 3.0?
In developer  site they are telling by default it will come.but for me it is not coming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some more info or possibly a screenshot would be helpful. Are you setting minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create Custom Title Bar Layout to add your own image in titlebar.And then you can use following code to assign the titlebar to your view

```
    boolean customTitleSupported;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    if (customTitleSupported) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_tittlebar_layout);         

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
```

here custom_tittlebar_layout refers to your custom titlebar layout with image.

Comment: The custom title bar feature in earlier Android versions and the action bar in Android 3 are different (and mutually exclusive) things.